# Was the Jewish month of Tammuz named after the pagan god Tammuz of the Babylonian?

Tags: hebrew, history, avodah-zarah

According to Wikipedia: "The name of the month was adopted from the Assyrian and Babylonian month Araḫ Dumuzu, named in honour of the Mesopotamian deity Dumuzid"

If so what's the implication about mention other gods before Yahweh in Exodus 23:13? Is it a violation?

Comment: There are only two answers given to this question in Mi Yodeya. The first is described by Aaron as unsatisfactory and the second doesn't answer the question at all.  Seems like the jury is still out on this one...